# Extjs data not loading completely

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using ExtJS and I noticed that it doesn't seem to load the full list. Its loads the partial list and hangs up.

I have to refresh or extend the `popupwindow` to load the data completely.

How can I fix this?

```
var mystore = new Ext.data.Store({
    url: '/jsonfeed&id=' + encodeURIComponent(this.idUrl),
    sorters: [{
        property: 'ImpactSummary',
        direction: 'DESC'
    }],
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        root: 'xml.RowElement',
        fields: [{
            name: 'DisplayName',
            mapping: 'DisplayName'
        }, {
            name: 'ImpactSummary',
            mapping: 'ImpactSummary',
            type: 'int'
        }, ]
    }),

});

var listView = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    store: mystore,
    multiSelect: false,
    splitHandleWidth: 10,
    width: 350,
    height: 670,

    columnLines: true,


    //reserveScrollOffset: true,
    renderTo: containerEl,

    columns: [{
        text: "DisplayName",
        dataIndex: 'DisplayName',
        renderer: showDisplayName,
        sortable: true,
        flex: 60
    }, {
        text: "ImpactSummary",
        dataIndex: 'ImpactSummary',
        renderer: showElementName,
        sortable: true,
        flex: 40
    }]
});
//pass along browser window resize events to the panel         
Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize(listView.doLayout, listView);
console.log('Ext version ' + Ext.version);
```

Comment: You added the jQuery tag; is something missing from your question that ties this into jQuery?

Comment: try console.log(mystore.data.items) and see if the data returned is what you expected. if it isn't then it could be the backend problem instead.

Answer (score 0):

which version of EXTjs are you using?

After create the store try force it to load:

```
mystore.load(function(records, operation, success) {
    enter code hereenter code here`console.log('loaded records');
});
```

Another test you can do is put your grid with 'autoScroll: true'

Comment: i tried the autoScroll:true.. did do anything.. i had manually close and reopen the popup window only then it shows the entire list

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before attempting to answer more questions.